# SpringAOP and Aspectj: Aspect to get all Logger calls

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, slf4j, spring-aop

I have two Java projects with Spring Boot and Maven:

- Backend-Client which communicates with a webservice
- MonitoringSystem Backend Client which is added as an external library to the first project and contanins the AOP implementation

In the later one I have one aspect which is already working in SpringAOP and reports every thrown error to the MonitoringSystem.

```
    @Pointcut("(within(foo.xy..*) || within(foo.doo..*)) && " +
            "!within(is(FinalType)) && " +
            "!within(is(EnumType))")
```

Now I am trying to set up a second one to catch every log entry created during runtime with the most common logging frameworks like SLF4J to write them in a separate log file. I tried this with the following pointcut expression:

```
    @Pointcut("call(* org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.*(..)) " +
            "|| call(* org.slf4j.Logger.*(..)) " +
            "|| call(* org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.*(..))")
    public void loggerCalls() {}
```

As this packages are not in the Spring context I tried this with loadTimeWeaving enabled:

```
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving

aop.xml set right

-javaagent:...\spring-instrument.jar
-Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true
```

But the aspect is never triggered. The frist one still runs like its supposed, but with a pretty long stacktrace which doesnt contain any usefull information for debugging.
The fun thing is, that this aspect worked for a time, but after a few changes I was never again able to make it work.

Even with the expression

```
 execution(public * *(..))
```

the aspect is not working, so i guess the weaving is just not working.

I have no clue where the problem is or how i can further track this down. What I can do next to make it work again. Is there a good example out there for my use case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You already provided a lot of information, which is great. Unfortunately, it is still fragmentary. The problems could be in many places. Please publish your MCVE on GitHub, so I can take a look. Thank you.